# Ajax callbacks fire in unexpected order

Tags: jquery

psuedo code:
     when( x,  y ).then(z);

where y is a call to a function that makes an ajax call as in:

```
function y(......){
  var p = $.ajax(...........);
  p.done(callMeFirst);
  return p;
}
```

Now from my understanding given that x is already resolved then on a successful ajax call 'callMeFirst' should fire first followed by 'z'

but what happens is that 'z' fires first and then 'callMeFIrst'

I don't get why that is happening or how to fix it as all our ajax calls run thru 'y' and its post call processing is needed before any other callback get to handle it.

TIA
Rob

Comment: That's because ajax is asynchronous. Solution would be to call z in p.done

Comment: I know ajax is async...

Thats why I am expecting first the 'callMeFirst' to fire as it was registered first and then 'z' to fire after that as it was registered second.

And I cant put it in p.done as z is dependent on both x and y completing whereas callMeFirst is only dependent on the ajax call completing

Comment: "when", "done" etc are written up nicely here: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: Could you illustrate it a little more? Your pseudo code works perfectly fine on my Chrome - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/w2aZV/)

Comment: @Fabricio
Your right!
My real code was more complex but on JSFiddle it worked, which made me look closer at my own code and I found a stupid mistake once I fixed that it worked as expected.
Thanks

Comment: @Ben - Indeed that article is very good - gave me some ideas for later.

Answer (score -1):

Use async for making it synchronized

```
return $.ajax({
       url  : url,
       type : "POST",
       cache: false,
       async:   false
}).responseText;
```

Comment: @moonwave99 -  Agreed, you should never set async false on ajax calls